# Aligning Contact and Open Oppty owners with Account owners

Tags: opportunity, account, contact

Lately we have been observing that all the Contacts and Open oppty owners in our org. are changing to the Account owner if there is a change in owner on the Account. We do not have any automation for this. The idea (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000XrJFAA0) is still open, so I assume salesforce has not released this feature yet. 
Just wondering how this is happening and thought of checking with others in this forum?

I have raised a ticket with Salesforce where they are in the middle of analysis and partially confirmed that this is not salesforce native functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is default functionality.

When account ownership is getting changed, all contacts which the account owner has, will be changed automatically.

When account ownership is changed, all open opportunities will be updated with new owner.

To transfer closed opportunities, checkbox needs to be selected.

[image: account ownership change]

Comment: Yes, I noticed it now. However, when we do bulk import this is not the case. It is not automatically updating the Contacts and Accounts.

Comment: Is my answer serves your purpose?